# CakePHPで本登録用のメールを送りたいです。

Tags: mysql, cakephp

CakePHPで会員登録フォームに入力されたメールアドレスに本会員登録用のリンクの貼られたメールを送りたいのですが、

```
Error:SQLSTATE[42000]:Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'getActiviationHash' at　line　1　SQL Query:getActiviationHash.
```

というエラーが発生しています。

CakePHPの経験が浅く、突破口が掴めずにいます。
どなたか以下のコードで問題箇所などが分かる方がいらっしゃったらご指摘頂きたいです。

```
public $components = array('Auth');

public function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->allow('signup');
}

public function signup()
{
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        if($this->User->save($this->data)){
            $url='activate/'.$this->User->id.'/'.$this->User->getActiviationHash();
            $url=Router::url($url,true);

            $email=new CakeEmail();
            $email->from(array('kentotamu@gmail.com' =>'Sender'));
            $email->to($this->data['User']['email']);
            $email->subject('Registration mail');
            $email->send($url);

            $this->Session->setFlash('Registration suceessful');
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('Error');
        }
    }
}
```

Cake/conf/Email.php

```
class EmailConfig {

public $default = array(
    'transport' => 'Mail',
    'from' => 'you@localhost',
    //'charset' => 'utf-8',
    //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
);

public $smtp = array(
    'transport' => 'ssl://Smtp.gmail.com',
    'from' => array('site@localhost' => 'My Site'),
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 587,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => false,
    //'charset' => 'utf-8',
    //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
);
```

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/192113 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/3060)

Comment: 表示されているエラーはMySQLのSQL文に関するものです。提示されたコードには詳細が含まれていませんが、実行したSQL文が正しいものかを確認する必要があると思います。

Comment: ご反応ありがとうございます。登録されたメールアドレスにメールを送るだけですので、SQL文は必要がなったかと認識しています。このgetActiviationHash付近の構文が問題みたいなのですが、MYsql5.6のバージョンに一致しいないなどの問題があるのかなと踏んでいます。

Comment: CakePHPのバージョンは2.xでしょうか

Comment: マルチポスト先で解決した場合は、解決した内容をこちらに自己回答などで展開し承認してください。未解決のまま質問が残ってしまいます。

Comment: マルチポスト失礼しました。対応します

Comment: CakePHP2.xになります。

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 2.x のモデルクラスにおいて、実装されていないメソッドを呼び出した場合は、そのメソッド名でSQL文が構築されます。

Userクラスに、 `getActiviationHash`メソッドを実装しているのでしょうが、 `$this->User` が、Userクラスではないため、このような事象となっています。
確認のために、`debug(get_class($this->User))`などとして、クラス名を確認してみてください。`AppModel`クラスとなっているはずです。

CakePHP 2.xのコントローラーでは、デフォルトでコントローラー名の単数形のモデルが使用できるようになっていますが、その呼び出し時にモデルクラスが規約に沿った場所になく見つからない場合は、`AppModel`クラスが代替として使用されます。

Userクラスが規約に添った場所（`app/Model/User.php`）として配置されているか確認してください。

Comment: 詳細なご説明ありがとうございます。デバックの結果AppModel がクラス名になります。ファイルのディレクトリとしてはapp/Model/User.phpに設置されています。

Comment: Modelは問題が無かったのですが、ポート番号を４６５に変更したところで解決いたしました。また、$url='activate/'.$this->User->id.'/'.$this->User->getActiviationHash();/ $url=Router::url($url,true);の２文を削除したところ正常に起動しました。ありがとうございました。